# Chef deployment with "$" dollar sign in string truncates encrypted password

Tags: ruby, cmd, escaping, chef-infra

I have a chef deployment that runs like this:

```
encryptedvalues = chef_vault_item(node.chef_environment, 'my_app_name')

do_windows_service "Installing Windows Service" do
    action :install
    #...
    app_config_changes ({
        "configuration/secureAppSettings/add[@key='XSWebserviceUser']/@value" => "#{encryptedvalues['XSWebserviceUser']}",
        "configuration/secureAppSettings/add[@key='XSWebservicePassword']/@value" => "#{encryptedvalues['XSWebservicePassword']}"
    })
end
```

I have determined that the values are correct, they are inserted into the correct position, and everything is fine, until the encrypted password value has "$" in it. I cannot change the password, and tried to escape it by wrapping it in an interpolated string: `"#{pass}"`, but unfortunately it didn't work. Any ideas on how I can get the deploy to succeed?

Originally in the app config it looks like

```
<secureAppSettings>
    <add key="XSWebserviceUser" value="XXX" />
    <add key="XSWebservicePassword" value="XXX" />
  </secureAppSettings>
```

and after deployment with a password="xyz#$%xyz"

```
<secureAppSettings>
    <add key="XSWebserviceUser" value="User" />
    <add key="XSWebservicePassword" value="xyz#" />
  </secureAppSettings>
```

Update: Checking the logs I see this in the server

```
4.  2020-01-08T23:36:36.3315043Z STDERR: Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Boolean". Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0.
```

Looks like it may actually be an issue with windows powershell?

Comment: Tip: Instead of `"#{x}"` just do `x`. It makes your code way more readable.

Comment: Can you check where the part of the password gets lost? Is it already returned like that from the vault, or is it inside the `do_windows_service`? (Print the value of encryptedvalues['XSWebservicePassword'] before the do_windows_service resource.)

Comment: Please post the source code of our `do_windows_service` resource. I bet the cause is hidden somewhere there.